# method toString throws KotlinReflectionInternalError

Tags: kotlin, reflection, kotlin-reflect

Why calling method `toString()` on function reference results in an error KotlinReflectionInternalError

```
fun main() {
    fun foo(){}
    ::foo.toString()
}
```

output:

```
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KotlinReflectionInternalError: Function 'foo' (JVM signature: main$foo()V) not resolved in class kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics$Kotlin: no members found
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl.findFunctionDescriptor(KDeclarationContainerImpl.kt:131)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KFunctionImpl$descriptor$2.invoke(KFunctionImpl.kt:56)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KFunctionImpl$descriptor$2.invoke(KFunctionImpl.kt:55)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:93)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:32)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KFunctionImpl.getDescriptor(KFunctionImpl.kt:55)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KFunctionImpl.toString(KFunctionImpl.kt:185)
    at kotlin.jvm.internal.FunctionReference.toString(FunctionReference.java:130)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt:3)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt)
```